# Jmeter - Do not use cache to retrieve results

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for load testing my ASP.NET application.

I am testing search functionality, what is the response time in getting the results.

The problem I am facing is when I search for the first time say I searched "I am good" and say it took 9876 milliseconds, next time I search the same thing it takes only 4567 milliseconds, third time 4234 milliseconds.

I am using HTTP CACHE MANAGER and i have checked "Clear cache each iteration". I have also used Http Cookie Manager and i have checked "Clear cookies each iteration"

My expectation is every time it run it should lie somewhere in that range only what it took for first search.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have everything correct at JMeter side. Maybe the server itself creating the cache. Try with different string each time/iteration. You can do that by appending a counter each time or something like that. If the results are different then chances that the application itself is creating a cache for same query/search string.